# How do Azure APIM Products behave with multiple Products without subscription required?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

While going through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#how-api-management-handles-requests-with-or-without-subscription-keys), I can not figure out which is the behaviour in case multiple Products include the same API, and none of them requires a Subscription Key. Still, those can have different Policies, changing completely the context of the request.

So, imagine one open Product has JWT validation and another one does not. Which Product would serve the request that does not include any Subscription Key? Would it try with both Products in random order until one has a successful response?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

[I raised the concern in the official docs feedback process](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/104520), and the answer is:
**An API can only be associated with one open product.**